# Replace all character to space until it meet the first /

Tags: bash, shell-script, sed, rhel

This is the string (it is the value of a shell variable):

```
2908104 /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7Server/Patches/gen
```

Expected output:

```
/var/cache/yum/x86_64/7Server/Patches/gen
```

How to retrieve only the value start from first /? I'm totally new in sed and just a beginner in linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the implementations of `grep` commonly found on systems that use Linux as their kernel (GNU's as found on RHEL and other general purpose GNU/Linux distributions, busybox as found on most Linux-based systems¹, toybox as found on Android), you can do:

```
LC_ALL=C grep -o '/.*' <input
```

To print the portion of the lines starting with the first `/` for those lines that have at least one.

POSIXly:

```
LC_ALL=C sed -n 's|^[^/]*/|/|p' <input
```

If the string is stored in a shell variable in a POSIX-like shell (like  the `sh` of RHEL which is actually `bash` in POSIX mode).

```
new_string=${string#"${string%%/*}"}
```

(`$new_string` will be empty if `$string` didn't contain any `/`)

`${string%%/*}` removes the longest suffix that matches `/*`. The result in turn is taken as the pattern in `${string#pattern}` which removes the shortest prefix matching the pattern. Here, as `${string%%/*}` is quoted it's taken as a literal string as opposed to a pattern.

With `zsh`, you can also do:

```
new_string=${(M)string%%/*}
```

With the `M` [parameter expansion flag](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion-Flags), all those `${string#pattern}` (or `##`, `:#`, `%`, `%%`) operators instead of removing the matching portion, expand to the `M`atched portion (the one that would be removed without it).

You could also remove all the leading non-/ characters:

- `zsh`:

  ```
  set -o extendedglob
  new_string=${string##[^/]#}
  ```
- `ksh93` / `bash -O extglob`:

  ```
  new_string=${string##*([^/])}
  ```

Where `X#` (zsh) or `*(X)` (ksh) matches 0 or more `X`s, the equivalent of regexp `X*` as used in `grep` or `sed` above.

---

<sup>¹ generally embedded though like in your smart lightbulbs or TVs or networking appliances, so it's rare for end-users to interact with their shells and utilities when they have some.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

To remove the initial part of the value of a shell variable up to (and including) the first space:

```bash
var=${var#* }
```

This removes the shortest prefix string matching the shell pattern `*`  ("star space") in the variable `var`.  See also the [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) section of the Bash manual, or [Parameter Expansion](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02) section of the POSIX standard.

Example:

```bash
$ var='2908104 /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7Server/Patches/gen'
$ var=${var#* }
$ printf 'var is "%s"\n' "$var"
var is "/var/cache/yum/x86_64/7Server/Patches/gen"
```

or, shorter (if no actual change to the variable is necessary),

```bash
$ var='2908104 /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7Server/Patches/gen'
$ printf 'The trimmed value of var is "%s"\n' "${var#* }"
The trimmed value of var is "/var/cache/yum/x86_64/7Server/Patches/gen"
```

If there are multiple spaces before the string that you want to isolate and you actually need to go by the `/`, then consider using the approach outlined in [Stéphane Chazelas' answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/716281/116858), replicated here:

```bash
var=${var#"${var%%/*}"}
```